# Oracle 10g express edition vs Mysql in python

Tags: python, mysql, oracle

Can't i use oracle 10g express edition for sql with python? as i have it installed in my pc. Or i need to hv mysql to use sql with python. I am learning DBMS this semester so i hv Oracle 10g and in Python there is database part too but basically we are using sql. So why install MYsql?

Comment: Yes, see https://oracle.github.io/python-cx_Oracle/

Comment: Oracle 10g is very old (around 2005). You should really consider downloading a more recent version if you can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

python is a programming language which can communicate with any database for which there exists a driver. For Oracle that is [cx_oracle](https://oracle.github.io/python-cx_Oracle/). MySQL has [a python connector](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/). PostgreSQL uses [the psycopg2 module](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-python/connect/).

So basically you can probably use whatever DBMS you are comfortable with. Unless your teacher has a specific flavour they want you to use. However, I would suggest you use a more recent version of Oracle XE than 10g. That's more than a decade old. I think you will have fewer driver compatibility issues if you use a modern version of whatever database you choose. For Oracle that's [XE 18c](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/xe-downloads.html).

Comment: Thnx. Yes i am having driver compatibility issues now. Thanks for this other advice too.